# JProfiler 5.2.4 + IBM WAS 7 64 bit, Java 1.6

Tags: jprofiler

I am trying to configure JProfiler and get the following error on launch in the WAS native_stderr.log file. I downloaded 64 bit Jprofiler 5 x version. The wizard configuration was clean. Not sure if this is WAS 64 bit issue or Jprofiler. Thanks!

JVMJ9TI001E Agent library jprofilerti could not be opened (jprofilerti.dll is not a valid Win32 application. )
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9jvmti24(-3): JVMJ9VM009E J9VMDllMain failed
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

You probably selected the wrong JVM bitness in the wizard. On the JVM step, select the "64-bit" JVM option, then it will load the 64-bit library.